# Array con una posición ocupada en JAVA

Tags: java, array, netbeans

Tengo un arreglo

```
int[] arr=new int[10];
```

el cual recibe 10 números(se pueden repetir) de un rango entre 1 y 7, estos números se tienen que acomodar de menor a mayor, el problema es cuando intento acomodarlos, ya que cada número tiene una posición, si existe un número que se repite n veces, tengo que buscar una posición que no tenga ningún valor incluido para agregar el valor repetido. Yo incluí un ciclo while:

```
while(arr[posicion] != 0){
    posicion--;
}
```

pero al correrlo me manda el siguiente error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

El index dado en la variable `posicion` es illegal, o está fuera de rango o es un número negativo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu bucle esta tratando de acceder un un indice en el arreglo del cual no existe valor, por esta razòn obtienes el error:

> ### Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Si deseas ordenar los nùmeros en el array puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
//Suponiendo estos son tus valores. 
arr = new int[]{7,5,3,5,1,2,4,6};

Arrays.sort(arr);       
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

salida con array ordenado:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Pero se supone que al declarar un arreglo vacío todos los espacios que se hagan son iguales a cero, ya lo verifique  con el mío.
Pero ahorita revisando creo que si hay una inconsistencia.

Ojala fuera tan facil, no puedo usar esas herramientas

Comment: Asì es, si solo lo dimensionas int[] arr = new int[10]; inicialmente estos son los valores:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] , lo que puse es solo un array con numeros del uno al 1 como ejemplo para que veas como al final se muestran los valores ordenados.

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que comentas el error que te lanza la excepcion
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Se puede estar dando, debido a que en la variable **posicion** estas pasando un valor fuera del rango del array ,en el caso de tu array ,las posiciones toman valores de 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  por lo tanto si pasas un parametro diferente a estos numeros te lanzara esta excepcion

Sin ver completamente el codigo ,diria que iniciaste la variable posicion en 10 ,lo cual es una posicion inexistente o tomo alguna posicion que no este en el rango del array